# is it possible to pointcut on a third party class and how?

Tags: java, spring, aop, ibatis, pointcut

I use spring and ibatis in my project, here is my question.

I want to trace all changes like `add/update/delete` and log them into table `T_TRACE_LOG`. The table has columns: `operation_type, object_type, log_content, log_date`.

Here is an example record:

```
"add", "customer", "name='andy',age=23,...", 2012-06-14 17:04:57.410
```

The log_content comes from `Customer.toString()`, I want this process automatically, so the AOP comes into my mind.

I can't control the client code, because some uses `addCustomer()` and some uses `insertCustomer()` and others use `createCustomer()`. But all of them called `getSqlMapClientTemplate().insert("inserCustomer", Customer)` at last. So I want to pointcut on `getSqlMapClientTemplate().insert()` to match them all.

Here is my trying, but it doesn't work:

```
 <aop:pointcut  expression="execution(* org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.insert(..))" id="insertLogPointCut"/>
```

It works If I change the expression as below:

```
<aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.xxx.CustomerDaoImpl.insert(..))" id="logPointCut"/>
```

Because AOP compiles the "pointcut information" into class bytecode based on source code, so I think it's impossible to pointcut on the ibatis class. If it's wrong, how to handle my situation?

Here is the configuration:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
<bean id="traceLogger" class="com.xx.TraceLogger"/>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.xx.CustomerDaoImpl.insert(..))" id="insertLogPointCut"/>
    <aop:aspect id="logAspect" ref="traceLogger">
        <aop:after-returning method="logAfterReturning" pointcut-ref="insertLogPointCut"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Comment: Is the client template class instantiated by spring?

Comment: Yes, it was instantiated by spring's ioc. SqlMapClientTemplate is injected into CustomerDaoImpl with reference "sqlMapClient", which points to org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean

Comment: Add info to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Can you show full configuration of aop from your `*-context.xml`?

Comment: Configuration added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Default AOP behavior in Spring only works with interface (because it is using Java's dynamic proxy).  It won't work if the pointcut is set on a concrete class.

SqlMapClientTemplate, if I remember correctly, is a class.

You have the choice of

1. using cg-lib for proxy creation, or
2. change your bean to use SqlMapClientOperations instead of SqlMapClientTemplate, and write have pointcut as "execution(* org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientOperations.insert(..))"

I shall recommend method 2.

And, your guess is wrong. AOP related stuff is not compiled into corresponding bytecode.  They are all done in runtime (for the case in Spring)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Spring AOP is different with AspectJ. Spring AOP uses dynamic proxy pattern so it functions in runtime. AspectJ's ajc compiles into the bytecode.

Comment: For your method2, I still don't know how. My `CustomerDaoImpl` extends from `SqlMapClientDaoSupport`, and I simply call `getSqlMapClientTemplate().insert("addCustomer", customer)` in my addCustomer(customer) method. Then how to use SqlMapClientOperations instead?

Comment: Thanks for your information. It's my fault, I found the problem. I called `getSqlMapClientTemplate().insert("addCustomer", customer)` in the DaoImpl's method, which is not a part of the Dao Interface, it's just called by another interface method in a loop (insert many customers). I added the method to the Dao interface and it works. Thanks!